# Passenger 5.0.21 error: Cannot connect to the Passenger core

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, debian, passenger, kerberos

I have problem with deploying RoR-app with apache2+passenger.
OS is debian-like Astra Linux.
Kerberos auth with GSSAPI is enabled.

*passenger-status* shows:

```
Version : 5.0.21
Date    : 2016-04-22 12:29:13 +0300
Instance: Dt5dmAVr (Apache/2.2.22 (Debian) mod_auth_kerb/5.4  Phusion_Passenger/5.0.21)

Phusion Passenger is currently not serving any applications.
```

With attempt to access app page from browser I get error message in */var/log/apache2/error.log* :

```
[ 2016-04-22 12:23:58.4672 21392/7f741705c780 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:234 ]: Passenger core running in multi-application mode.
[ 2016-04-22 12:23:58.4685 21392/7f741705c780 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:707 ]: Passenger core online, PID 21392
[ 2016-04-22 12:23:58.4897 21407/7f4819471780 age/Ust/UstRouterMain.cpp:504 ]: Starting Passenger UstRouter...
[ 2016-04-22 12:23:58.4912 21407/7f4819471780 age/Ust/UstRouterMain.cpp:317 ]: Passenger UstRouter online, PID 21407
[Fri Apr 22 12:23:58 2016] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Debian) mod_auth_kerb/5.4 Phusion_Passenger/5.0.21 configured -- resuming normal operations
[ 2016-04-22 12:24:18.0666 21428/7f3a64646780 apa/Hooks.cpp:703 ]: Unexpected error in mod_passenger: Cannot connect to the Passenger core at unix:/tmp/passenger.N6n3OMb/agents.s/core
  Backtrace:
     in 'Passenger::FileDescriptor Hooks::connectToCore()' (Hooks.cpp:305)
     in 'int Hooks::handleRequest(request_rec*)' (Hooks.cpp:573)
```

With passenger-5.0.27 everything looks same.

Passenger was installed as gem.

*/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/passenger.load*:

```
LoadModule passenger_module /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/passenger-5.0.21/buildout/apache2/mod_passenger.so
```

*/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/passenger.conf*:

```
<IfModule mod_passenger.c>
   PassengerRoot /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/passenger-5.0.21
   PassengerDefaultRuby /usr/local/bin/ruby
</IfModule>
```

*/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/myapp*:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName myapp.ru
    ServerAlias www.myapp.ru
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    DocumentRoot /var/www/myapp/public
    RailsEnv production
    <Directory /var/www/myapp/public/>
        AuthType Kerberos
        KrbAuthRealms EXAMPLE.RU
        KrbServiceName HTTP/astra-server.example.ru
        Krb5Keytab /etc/apache2/keytab
        KrbMethodNegotiate on
        KrbMethodK5Passwd off
        require valid-user
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    LogLevel warn
</VirtualHost>
```

Any help?

Comment: For passenger 4.0.60 i have this error [ 2016-04-22 16:07:50.0106 29764/7eff74cbf780 apache2/Hooks.cpp:732 ]: Unexpected error in mod_passenger: Cannot connect to the helper agent at /tmp/passenger.1.0.29629/generation-1/request
  Backtrace:
     in 'Passenger::FileDescriptor Hooks::connectToHelperAgent()' (Hooks.cpp:291)
     in 'int Hooks::handleRequest(request_rec*)' (Hooks.cpp:546)

Comment: If it helps to find answer - apache2 uses prefork mode. apache2-mpm-prefork package is installed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[PassengerInstanceRegistryDir](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/config/apache/reference/#passengerinstanceregistrydir) option helped me.

### UPDATE

Whole solution for Apache+Passenger sockets processing on Astra Linux SE:

- Apache user - www-data (/etc/apache2/envvars)
- Passenger user switching is on (by default)
- Passenger instance dir is moved to /var/passenger (PassengerInstanceRegistryDir option in /etc/apache2/mods-available/passenger.conf)
- Astra Linux specific - www-data user has Linux (CAP_SETGID, CAP_SETUID) and PARSEC (PARSEC_CAP_PRIV_SOCK, PARSEC_CAP_SETMAC) priviledges. This priviledges can be set via `usercaps` command.
- Directories /var/www, /var/passenger are owned by www-data

Answer (score 2):

It could be that your /tmp dir is being cleaned by something. Check if the /tmp dir from the log actually exists or not if you see the error. You can fix that by stopping the cleaning or changing the [PassengerInstanceRegistryDir](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/config/apache/reference/#passengerinstanceregistrydir) to another place than /tmp.

Another possibility is that your shell is exiting somehow (Passenger uses the shell to execute commands, which will fail if the shell exits prematurely).

Either way setting the PassengerLogLevel to 7 should provide more information.